# $state.go() does not call the controller first time on click of Button

Tags: javascript, cordova, controller, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I'm a newbie to Ionic Development, and facing a rather strange problem.

I have two pages Home Page and Save Template Page with HomeCtrl and SaveTemplateCtrl respectively.

From my Save Template Page I'm redirecting to Home page.

***The problem is onClick of Save Button redirection happens but the Home Page controller is not called for the First Time. The successive times the HomeCtrl is called.***

Code is as below:

HomeCtrl:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Template) {
  alert("Within Home Controller");
})
```

SaveTemplateCtrl :

```
.controller('SaveTemplateCtrl ', function($scope) {

    $scope.saveTemplate = function(template) {
     //**Logic for Saving the Template
     setTimeout(function() {
       alert("Going to Home Controller");
       $state.go('myapp.home');
    },1200);
   };

 })
```

Advice and Help me to Solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance, 
:)

Comment: update your ques with state declaration..!and html also..!

Comment: Can you provide the $stateProvider.state() declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *Home Page* is default page, when you go to Home page first time, the **HomeCtrl** will be executed. But if you have not disabled *Home Page's* cache, when you redirect to *Home Page* from *Save Template Page*, the **HomeCtrl** would not be excuted again because of ionic view cache mechanism. For performance, we should try best not to disable cache. If you need execute some functions every time you enter in, maybe you could put them in `$ionicView.beforeEnter` event handler:

```
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Template) {
      $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
        alert("Within Home Controller");
      });
    })
```

More about ionic view lifecycle, please refer to http://www.gajotres.net/understanding-ionic-view-lifecycle/. Hope this will help you. Regards.

Comment: A hundred thanks buddy, you've made my day. This works like a charm. Learned a new concept .

Comment: @Mufaddal Glad that could help you.